# STM32F407VG DISCOVERY BOARD micro controller CAN messages

Tags: microcontroller, c, stm32, can, c++

I am wondering if anyone is familiar with any STM32f407VG
micro-controllers?

If so, I am having some problems configuring a CAN driver.
I can run the demo code, which is set to a loop-back mode, but I cannot get
normal mode to work.

I think message is not going out of the transmit mailbox. Status is going
to pending all the time.

I read through all the data sheets, and everything is configured
correctly except the INAK in the CAN_MSR register never resets to 0.
I can provide more detail if needed, but first I need to know if
there is someone who has worked with a STM32F4 microcontroller and
CAN messages.

Here is my sample code:

```
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(CAN_CLK, ENABLE); 
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);  
GPIO_PinAFConfig(CAN_GPIO_PORT, CAN_RX_SOURCE, CAN_AF_PORT);  
GPIO_PinAFConfig(CAN_GPIO_PORT, CAN_TX_SOURCE, CAN_AF_PORT); 
/* Configure CAN RX and TX pins */   
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = CAN_RX_PIN | CAN_TX_PIN;  
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;  
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;  
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;  
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_UP;  
GPIO_Init(CAN_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);   
CAN_DeInit(CANx);
CAN_StructInit(&CAN_InitStructure);   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TTCM = DISABLE;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_ABOM = DISABLE;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_AWUM = DISABLE;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_NART = DISABLE;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_RFLM = DISABLE;  
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TXFP = DISABLE;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Mode = CAN_Mode_Normal;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_SJW = CAN_SJW_1tq;
/* CAN Baudrate = 1 MBps (CAN clocked at 30 MHz) */   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS1 = CAN_BS1_6tq;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS2 = CAN_BS2_8tq;   
CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler = 2;  
CAN_Init(CANx, &CAN_InitStructure);

/************transmit message config***********/

TxMessage.StdId = 0x11;   
TxMessage.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;  
TxMessage.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;   
TxMessage.DLC = 2;   
TxMessage.Data[0] = 0xCA;   
TxMessage.Data[1] = 0xFE;

CAN_Transmit(CANx, &TxMessage);
uwCounter = 0;   
while(( CAN_TransmitStatus(CANx, TransmitMailbox)  !=  CANTXOK) && (uwCounter  !=  0xFFFF))   
{
    uwCounter++;   
}  
uwCounter = 0;   
while((CAN_MessagePending(CANx, CAN_FIFO0) < 1) && (uwCounter  != 0xFFFF))   
{
    uwCounter++;   
} 
k = CAN_TransmitStatus(CANx, i);
```

Comment: You are mentioning **two** chips. Pick one.

Comment: Do you have a CAN interface chip that is connected to a CAN network?  If so, please describe

Comment: I am using two stm32f4-discovery board and mcp2551 transceiver that connects between two boards

Comment: You need 2 CAN controllers (microcontrollers), each with their own transceiver (for example mcp2551). And the bus needs  two terminating resistors of 120 Ohm. Is this the case? Also note that the two boards will not start synchronously. The first node to start have to expect CAN errors until the point where another CAN controller is active on the bus.

Comment: i have two 120 ohm terminating resistors .both controllers are active on bus . problem is when i send message it is loading into can txmailbox and it not going out of mail box . i have cheak the status of mail box it is showing status as pending .if it is in loop mode it is working fine

Comment: Do you have a scope available, to check if CAN frames are actually getting out to the CAN bus?

Comment: we have scope when it in debug mode . we can cheak by calling can transmit status function

Comment: I mean, do you have an oscilloscope that you can use to actually probe the CAN HIGH and CAN LOW signals on the CAN bus to see if ant CAN frames are being transmitted?

Comment: i have oscilloscope but iam unable to see any message their .messages are not going out of can txmailbox it is showing as status pending all time this my code .https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4caGKjcLu5gckZ0WUdDMjZpUkU    .help me if u can